# repeated whole vector sampling in r

Tags: r, loops, random

I have following type of data

```
ntrt = paste ("EL", 1:4, sep= "")
repl = 3
```

I want to sample from the ntrt, but 3 times (rep =3), output something like below:

```
nsam <- c(sample(ntrt),sample(ntrt), sample(ntrt)) 
repl <- rep (1:3, each = length (ntrt))
newd <- data.frame (nsam, repl)
newd 
 nsam repl
1   EL3    1
2   EL1    1
3   EL4    1
4   EL2    1

5   EL2    2
6   EL4    2
7   EL1    2
8   EL3    2

9   EL1    3
10  EL3    3
11  EL4    3
12  EL2    3
```

Here is my trial to loop:

```
nsam <- rep (NULL, ntrt)
for (i in 1:rep){
         nsam[i] <- sample(ntrt)
         }
```

Edits: just clarification

```
ntrt
[1] "EL1" "EL2" "EL3" "EL4"

> sample(ntrt,4)
[1] "EL4" "EL3" "EL2" "EL1" 

# is equal to:
sample(ntrt)

but what I need:
c(sample(ntrt), sample(ntrt), sample(ntrt))

[1] "EL4" "EL3" "EL1" "EL2" "EL1" "EL2" "EL3" "EL4" "EL3" "EL1" "EL2" "EL4"

which is equal to 
c(sample(ntrt,4), sample(ntrt,4), sample(ntrt,4))
```

[image]

**Thus the process is:**

```
# for repl = 1
sample from ntrt  size = length(ntrt)

# repeat the same process again
# for repl = 2
sample from ntrt  size = length(ntrt)
# note: I only concerned with order of names within ntrt (randomization process)

# repeat the same process again
# for repl = 3
sample from ntrt  size = length(ntrt)

same process for n levels of repl
```

I am getting error, sorry for a simple question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `lapply`:

```
set.seed(1) # Just so you can compare -- remove for your actual purposes
ntrt = paste ("EL", 1:4, sep= "")
repl <- rep (1:3, each = length (ntrt))
nsam = unlist(lapply(1:3, FUN=function(i) sample(ntrt)))
newd <- data.frame (nsam, repl)
# > newd
# nsam repl
# 1   EL2    1
# 2   EL4    1
# 3   EL3    1
# 4   EL1    1
# 5   EL1    2
# 6   EL3    2
# 7   EL2    2
# 8   EL4    2
# 9   EL3    3
# 10  EL1    3
# 11  EL4    3
# 12  EL2    3
```

### Update

I noticed that @joran had already recommended `replicate` in a comment. Here's the replicate approach:

```
data.frame(nsam = as.vector(replicate(3, sample(ntrt))), repl)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to learn to use the help facilities in R. The `sample` function should do what you appear to be asking is you just submit a second argument:

```
?sample      # to get the help page
nsam <- sample(ntrt, 3)
nsam
#[1] "EL2" "EL1" "EL4"
```

To repeat permutation 3 times:

```
replicate(3, sample(ntrt, length(ntrt)))
```

Comment: please see my edits for what I intend to do, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @ram `replicate` perhaps? Your "clarification" didn't clarify much for me.

Comment: @joran I put a figure to illustrate the process, if that helps, basically idea is repeat the sample function sample(ntrt,4) number of repl